# Nuxt3 Pass data from app.vue to a layout or page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-props

In app.vue I have

```html
<template>
  <Html :class="theme">
    <Body>
      <NuxtLayout>
        <NuxtPage/>
      </NuxtLayout>
    </Body>
  </Html>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { AppSetup } from './utils/app';
import { ITheme } from './utils/theme';
AppSetup()
const theme = useState<ITheme>('theme.current')
</script>
```

This is what I see in the Vue devtools
[image]

And Even that the `<Html :class="theme">` is filled with the `theme` value. If I try to:

```html
<template>
  <Html :class="theme">
    <Body>
      <NuxtLayout :theme="theme">
        <NuxtPage :theme="theme" />
      </NuxtLayout>
    </Body>
  </Html>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { AppSetup } from './utils/app';
import { ITheme } from './utils/theme';
AppSetup()
const theme = useState<ITheme>('theme.current')
</script>
```

Then the `theme` property is not visible from the `layouts/default.vue` (there's only that one) or the `pages/index.vue`

How can I access to that prop? If not, what's the easier way? I tried in `pages/index.vue` to add the same code

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { AppSetup } from '../utils/app';
import { ITheme } from '../utils/theme';
AppSetup()
const theme = useState<ITheme>('theme.current')
</script>
```

And this works but feels like kinda repetitive (and this doesn't work in the `layouts/default.vue`

This is my `layouts/default.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <slot />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'default'
}
</script>
```

And this is what I see in the devtools (the value exist)
[image: ![enter image description here]

And this is my `pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>Welcome to <span class="text-gradient">Nuxt3</span> for {{ brand }}</h1>
  </main>
</template>
```

And this is what I see in the devtools (the value exists)
[image]

Comment: You're using `layout` or `layouts`? Should be the second one. Double check with your Vue devtools to see if you have what you expect there. Because it should work well so far. Double check what your have in your `theme` variable too.

Comment: oh, that was a typo. Yes is in `layouts/default.vue`, `theme` has a value ( it fills the `html[class]` but in child components/pages is not visible

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools? What is inside that theme? Is it supposed to be a global token in the same way as Tailwind? If so, it's even probably wiser to just have it as a global state in your app since it will be used everywhere. Either with Pinia or even with [`provide/inject`'s pattern](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html). Having it passed one by one will be cumbersome and quite time consuming.

Comment: Updated the question with an screenshot of what I see in the devtools selecting the app

Comment: `'bar'` is indeed in the `prop`. What about the other places? Does it appear in the devtools? Do you have it as a prop? Did you used `defineProps` there?

Comment: Updated the answer of what I see selecting the layout or the index page.
Also tried to install pinia (this prop think is my plan b like as you said would be too repetitive but i'm just doing a POC) but I get this error `npm --save-dev install pinia
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.41` any idea?

Comment: You have it as you can see. Now use, `defineProps` to receive it as a prop as explained in Vue's doc. Not sure about the NPM issue since it's NPM eh. Give a try to `npm i pinia -f`. Otherwise try to see if there is some sneaky package in your `package.json`. Or you could give yarn/pnpm a try to have a proper error (npm is quite bad at that as you can see).

Comment: thank you very much @kissu I successfully was able to instal pinia using yarn so I will follow your suggestion. I guess I'll leave this question open for now

Comment: So far, everything works great. You have Pinia, you have your state passed down properly. Everything is working well tbh. I should probably post an answer haha.

Comment: Yes but the question is about the Props, if I have the time I'll try to fix the code and provide an answer :) thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your devtools, the props are properly passed down, you need to received them now.
For that, you could use the following in your `index.vue` file

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  theme: String
})
</script>
```

More details available here: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits